# Save outputs to variable between multiprocessing processes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am looking a simple solution that save outputs to single file or single variable when I use multiprocessing.

my output is a list, when I try to join everything at the end of my multiprocessing, there is an error

Another option is to save a file in each step of the output function, but it takes a lot of memory

Is there a way to save this list between multiprocessing processes?

```
def calculate(data,ylat,xlon):
    output = []
    for j,i in data:
       ...
       output.append(lat,lon,area,fraction_area)
    L.append(output)
    print(lat,lon,area,fraction_area,file=f)
return output

# Multiprocessing
# number of polygons are 1200000
f=open('name.txt','w')
with mp.Manager() as manager:
   L = manager.list()
   pool = mp.Pool() 
   for index,polys in area_study.iterrows():
      # Limits each polygon in shapefile     
      ylat = [ymin,ymax]
      xlon= [xmin,xmax]
      args.append((polys,ylat,xlon))

   p=pool.starmap(calculate,args) 
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
```

Comment: If you want to share a file/variable between threads, I believe you must use [Semaphores](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) to allow a single thread to access the variable/file, lock it, and then release it to let other threads to access

Comment: try using generators!!

Comment: Where exactly i can use semaphores?? .. how do I use generators??

Comment: Why are you appending `output` to a managed list when the return value from `pool.starmap` will be a *regular* `list` with the same content (assuming you correct your indentation error). If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above about appending to a managed list seeming to be a needless operation.

I would use a generator function that yields successive `(polys, ylat, xlon)` tuples in conjunction with the `Pool.imap` method (and an efficient *chunksize* argument) that can lazily generate all the arguments as you go along and process the return values from `compute` writing the results from the main process as they become available. This is the general idea, which you can adapt as required.

Note that in your function `calculate` that the statement `output.append(lat,lon,area,fraction_area)` is invalid since `append` takes only a single argument. I am assuming in the code below that you are attempting to append a tuple (or list):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def calculate(t):
    data, ylat, xlon = t # unpack
    output = []
    for j, i in data:
       ...
       output.append((lat, lon, area, fraction_area))
    return output

def compute_chunksize(poolsize, iterable_size): 
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * poolsize)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def generate_polygons():
    for index, polys in area_study.iterrows():
       # Limits each polygon in shapefile     
       ylat = [ymin,ymax]
       xlon = [xmin,xmax]
       yield polys, ylat, xlon

# Required for Windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # number of polygons is 1200000
    poolsize = mp.cpu_count()
    # Best guess as to the size of the iterable being passed to imap:
    iterable_size = 1_200_000
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(poolsize, iterable_size)
    with open('name.txt', w) as f:
        pool = mp.Pool(poolsize)
        # Each result is a list of tuples of lat, lon, area, fraction_area
        for result in pool.imap(calculate, generate_polygons(), chunksize=chunksize):
            for t in result:
                print(*t, file=f)
                """
                lat, lon, area, fraction_area = t # unpack
                print(lat, lon, area, fraction_area, file=f)
                """
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```